# CSS shape with inset curve and transparent background

Tags: html, css, svg, css-shapes

I need to create a CSS shape like this image..

[image]

Please check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KB2nY/) of my work
I have created something like that, but I cannot give a curve to it.

```
#shape {     
    border-left: 70px solid transparent;
    border-top: 100px solid red;
    height: 0;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: does the white part have to be transparent or would a color be ok?

Comment: This URL helped me a lot some time ago to learn and understand how can you play with pseudoelements to make many diff shapes. I recomend you to check it out:http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Comment: white part should be transparent @NicoO

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a pseudo element with border-radius and background-shadows to create the curve and enable a **transparent background** for the curve.

Output :

[image: CSS Shape with thransparent inset curve]

```css
#shape {
  width: 300px; height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#shape:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%; right: 0;
  width: 300%;
  padding-bottom: 300%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: none;
  box-shadow: 10px -10px 5px 300px #F15723;
  z-index: -1;
}

body{background:url(https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8461/8048823381_0fbc2d8efb.jpg);background-size:cover;}
```

```html
<div id="shape"></div>
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/38GJA/)

Comment: Hey, I added on a page, but got a problem, you are using a white color, but I need to add it above section, so the curve should be transparent.. Can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: Sorry, need to ask one more thing :(
I need to add some text inside that div. How to do that?
When I am adding it does not show up.

Comment: Use `z-index` property to display the pseudo element behind the content of your div : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/38GJA/5/

Comment: I got that working by making the anchor tags position abs..
can you pls check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24699139/getting-error-in-website-width-in-fixed-layout-website
Can you tell me what is wrong? Hope you can fix this.. :)

Answer (score 1):

### Variant #01:

CSS3 [`linear-gradient()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient) can draw this background as well:

**CSS:**

```
div {
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 50px, tomato 50px);
}
```

**Output Image:**

[image]

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(lightgreen, green);
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}
div {
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 50px, tomato 50px);
  height: 150px;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  
</div>
```

### Variant #02:

We can use `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements and use css3 transformation to make this shape with round corners.

[image: Output Image with round corners]

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(lightgreen, green);
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}
div {
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 400px;
}
div:before {
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
  transform-origin: 100% 0;
  transform: skewY(45deg);
  background: tomato;
  position: absolute;
  width: 45px;
  z-index: -1;
  content: '';
  bottom: -5px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
div:after {
  border-radius: 0 10px 10px 10px;
  background: tomato;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: 35px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>

</div>
```

Comment: I think you must have missed this statement in the question - *but I cannot give a curve to it.*. Your answer doesn't produce a curve.

Comment: @Harry yes, you are right. I'll try to update my answer or delete it if couldn't make it.

Comment: Still not sure if this is what OP was after. I think they were looking for the cut itself to be curved but the screenshot seems different. Anyway I'll leave it here and maybe the OP will respond :)

Comment: @Harry Ok, I'll update my answer if OP will come with clarify required behavior.