# Getting error in website width in fixed layout website

Tags: html, css

I am getting a problem in fixed layout website.

I have coded it manually and do not know how to fix it. I am still on learning stage.
Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Problem:  [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhDae.jpg]
You can check the work [here](http://coder.esy.es/). Uploaded files to free domain.

Or CHeck js [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mDFN8/)...

```
<div class="navbar">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h3><a class="" href="#intro">Nature Experience</a></h3>
    </div>
</div>
<section id="intro">
    <div class="wrapper slogan">
        <h2>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type </h2>
    </div>
</section>
<section id="second">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h3 class="">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type </h3>
        <p class=" ">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type </p>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="blogcontainer ">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="text">
                        <strong class="">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy</strong>
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="text">
                        <strong class="">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy</strong>
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="text">
                        <strong class="">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy</strong>
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<section id="contact">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h3 class="">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing</h3>
        <div class="container">
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<section id="footer">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="left">
            <a href="#">CONTACT</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>


/*Reset css*/
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,del, dfn, em, img, 
ins, kbd, q, s, samp,small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,b, u, i, center,dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,fieldset, form, label, legend,table, caption, tbody, tfoot, 
thead, tr, th, td,article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}
body{
    font-family: 'Arvo', serif;
    text-align: center;
}
h3{
    font-size: 30px;
}
.wrapper{
    width: 1140px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.container{
    width: 1100px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    float: left;
}
.navbar {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 999;
}
#intro {
    background: url("http://hdwallpaperszon.in/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/HD-Black-Car-Wallpaper_31.jpg") no-repeat fixed 50% 0 / cover  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#intro h2 {
    font-size: 24px;
}
#intro .slogan {
    padding-top: 130px;
}
#second{
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 65px 0 55px;
    background: #666666;
    color: #fff;
}
#second  .blogcontainer{
    float: left;
}
#second  .blogcontainer .row{
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 10px 0;
}
#second  .blogcontainer .row .text{
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 26px;
    padding: 14px 0;
}
#contact{
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 65px 0 70px;
    background: #ECE8E1;
    color: #000;
}
#footer{
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px 0 35px;
    background: #666666;
    color: #fff;
}
#footer .left{
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: left;
    padding-top: 25px;
}
#footer .left a{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: posting an image wont help kindly make fiddle and ask ur question ?

Comment: Seems ok in Firefox(?)

Comment: you use `.container` and `.wrapper` class with fixed width. change it t0 100%

Comment: This is where I uploaded my code: http://coder.esy.es/ Check.

Comment: @TamilSelvan then will i mention my width for site?

Comment: I think your site is fluid type, so as mention the width as 100% for html container

Comment: Working for me in Chrome. What's the issue?

Comment: I need to make it fixed, no responsive.. how to fix fluid type? I have added html, body as width 100%, same problem

Comment: @Ranveer open in chrome.. Resize the browser width and then scroll the content, and then see..

Comment: Check out my answer. Is that what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to do [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mDFN8/4/)

CSS

```
 body {
min-width: 1140px;
}
```

Comment: No :(. By this the site will become responsive, and I need it to be fixed, no content wrapping.. You see in facebook, when you decrease the browser width /resolution the content does not wrap, but a horizontal scroll appear.. I need same.

Comment: Yes :) But I do not understand why body is asking for min width?
Can you explain?

Comment: Because you have .wrapper and  .container with width: 1140px; and body gets the width of window. which is less then 1140px.

Comment: I can;t vote up, but I can accept only. Thanks Again.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have used pixels for body or container division width. Try % for width.

e.g.

```
body or container (which u have used) {
width:100%;
margin-left:auto; 
margin-right: auto; 
}
```

Also see for image size width and height. It should be in % instead of pixel as it is single image with fixed size.

Because your sample page is looking OK with 1024 x 768 or more resolution (It is also looking some problem with exact 1024 x 768 resolution...).

EDIT :

updated ur wrapper and container css code

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mDFN8/1/)**

Now u can see difference by changing result section width and height in this jsfiddle

Comment: Can yous see here: http://jsfiddle.net/mDFN8/
Scroll horizontal and you can see problem

Comment: No, it is still not working.. Check http://s30.postimg.org/ycsrir22p/Untitled.jpg  I need to have the background color full width but when you scroll y, you see the cutted data